# how to receive url parameter with + sign

Tags: java, rest, query-string

I need to receive a parameter as QueryParam in my REST API which is present with + sign as below -

```
http://www.paramtesting.com/abc/api?param=+RES
```

when I receive the above param in REST API as `@QueryParam` I only get RES instead of +RES.

I could not find a suitable resolution on googling. please help.

Comment: First, you don't get `"RES"`, you get `" RES"`, and it happens because the `+` sign is decoded to a space. For webapp to receive a `+` sign, it needs to be encoded as `%2B`, i.e. `http://www.paramtesting.com/abc/api?param%2BRES`

Comment: `+` means "space" in URLs. you need to encode your URL to get it like this `http://www.paramtesting.com/abc/api?param=%2BRES`

Comment: but the actual value of field param to pass is +RES, so can we somehow pass +RES as is, or tell the api accessor method to call with %2B ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Encoder/Decoder in UI and Your controller.

UI

```
var encoded = encodeURIComponent(yourUrl);  // enocode with UTF-8
```

Controller

```
java.net.URLDecoder.decode("3qe80L1ap+cR2zRU9csFwOffw5NtWTueLRYgSXyjctI="));
```